# Command-line option to compare 2 images in FastStone Image Viewer

Tags: command-line, comparison, command-line-arguments, image-viewer, file-comparison

I find *FastStone Image Viewer* a useful freeware to compare 2 images side by side, by selecting the images (by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking) in its *Browser* view, then pressing <kbd>P</kbd>.

Is there a command-line option to directly compare images as above? e.g. something like

```
"C:\Program Files\FastStone Image Viewer\FSViewer.exe" "D:\image1.jpg" "D:\image2.jpg"
```

Comment: FastStone is great, but I don't think it has any command-line options. If you really need to do this, you'd be better off using something else.

Comment: IrfanView (www.irfanview.com) is more simple than FastStone, but it have command line options. You should have a look to it.